# What is the difference in setState notation?

Tags: reactjs

I find everywhere this sentence

```
this.setState({})
```

but when I use it in arrow function, it throws me an error "*this.setState is not a function*"

```
class ListWrapper extends React.Component {
   exampleFn = () => {
      this.setState({ // Error o.O
         // Do something...
      })
   }

   render(){ 
      return( //... )
   }
}
```

but when I add an equal sign behind setState it works

```
class ListWrapper extends React.Component {
   exampleFn = () => {
      this.setState = ({
         // Do something...
      })
   }

   render(){ 
      return( //... )
   }
}
```

So why is this the case and what is the difference between the two records?

Comment: Are you sure the second example is actually have the behavior you expect? Presumably it doesn't cause an error, but it doesn't look like it's actually setting the state either.

Comment: I can't really reproduce your issue. Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-nightingale-7giel?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: What error do you get in the first case? As @aprokryfos says, it should work. And as JLRishe says, the second block of code looks incorrect (it won't react to state changes).

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, this is my first project in React and many things are still magic for me, but when debugging I see that the state changes so "I think" works as it should

in the first case it appears that "this.setState is not a function"

* If someone wanted to have a look at the entire code [link](https://github.com/GrzegorzStacel/react_english_gramar_exercises/tree/master/src)

Comment: In the repo you shared you use a lot of `this.setState = ({...})` this is wrong and will overwrite the `setState` function with the object you've passed because `=` is an assignment. Just be consistent everywhere and use `this.setState({})` without the `=` and you should be fine

Comment: You were actually right @apokryfos ! I deleted all the equal signs and it works as it should :) Thanks a lot for your help, I sincerely doubt I'd figure it out myself :|